# Amazon s3 problems with gif files using urllib2 (python)

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, urllib2

We are using urllib2 to upload images to s3:

```
img_url = pic
imgData = urllib2.urlopen(img_url).read()
unipart.coverart = store_in_s3_partpic(name, imgData)


def store_in_s3_partpic(name, content):
    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    pathtofile = "partpics/%s" % (name)
    b = conn.create_bucket('bucketname')
    k = Key(b)
    path = "/media/" + pathtofile
    k.key = path
    k.set_contents_from_string(content)
    k.set_acl("public-read")
    return pathtofile
```

JPG files load properly, but GIF files consistently give the following error when we go to the file URL on Amazon:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>E9482112F0EBAAD7</RequestId>
<HostId>
9Xoh6fuKdsDIwYASEg64VHt5sxw1aYXmmBGtacsG1JYMgr18GUooZReB5WyRN1TW
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are the permissions for the s3 folder set correctly?

Comment: Well considering I can get JPG that is uploaded using the exact same code to the same bucket/place and accessed the same way, I would think so. Is there a possibility that permissions would allow access to JPG files but not GIFs?

Comment: Not that I know of. :P